# sending friend requests from facebook apps using direct URI

Tags: php, facebook, uri, facebook-php-sdk

am trying to invite my facebook friens to use my application using the following code:

```
 <?php $this->config->load('facebook'); 


 $sendFriendRequest = array(

'description' => 'join market place',
'redirect_uri' => urlencode('http://apps.facebook.com/morganmarket')
 );

?>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
app_id=<?php echo $this->config->item('appId');?>&
message=<?php echo $sendFriendRequest['description'];?>&
redirect_uri=<?php echo $sendFriendRequest['redirect_uri'];?>"/>
<img src=<?php echo base_url().'public/images/web/facebook/friendrequests.png';?> />
</a>
```

the problem that,am not directed to the send requests to friends dialogue directly, but iam directed to a page with the following link (go to facebook.com), how can i get redirected to the dialogue first without getting redirected to the dialogue directly?

Answer (score 0):

try using following direct url:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=APP_ID&
message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/morganmarket

After the user follows the flow and sends the request the browser will redirect to

http://apps.facebook.com/morganmarket?request=REQUEST_ID&to=ARRAY_OF_USER_IDS

If there are errors, the browser will redirect to

http://apps.facebook.com/morganmarket?error_code=ERROR_CODE&error_msg=ERROR_MSG